# Regex: How to get regex from html

Tags: html, regex, google-sheets

How do I convert the following html to regex, I'm trying to get the text between the h1 tags.

I need the regex as I need to use it in a google sheets formula.

```
<h1 class="ch-title" style="text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 1px 2px;">
Text to get
</h1>
```

I'm not sure how to get it,

**Edit 1:** I need the regex to use within a google sheets formula.

**Edit 2:** I've managed to get the following regex to recognise

REGEX

```
<h1 class="ch-title">\n?(.*)\n?<\/h1>
```

HTML

```
<h1 class="ch-title">
Text to get
</h1>
```

However how do I negate the following from the regex.

```
style="text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 1px 2px;"
```

EDIT 3: I managed to get the [regex](https://regexr.com/5mtro) negating the style tag

```
<h1 class="ch-title"[a-z=":;,.0-9\s?()-]*>\n?(.*)\n?<\/h1>
```

I'm not sure it's correct

Comment: Do you have this element in the DOM or is it in the form of a string? There is [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) if you want to parse the HTML string to a document object.

Comment: It's being used within a google sheets function importregex based on this article - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97629/why-wont-importxml-work-on-this-sheet

Comment: Not sure if google sheets allows [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). You can try `let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(yourHTMLString, 'text/html')` and then use `doc.querySelector` or any other DOM API methods.

Comment: `<h1 class="ch-title"[^>]*>\n?(.*)\n?<\/h1>`

Comment: Have you try  >\n?(.*)\n?<

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, instead of negating I included the style tag.

```
<h1 class="ch-title".*?>(.*)<\/h1>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following in cell `A1`:

```
<h1 class=""ch-title"" style=""text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 1px 2px;"">
Text to get
</h1>
```

You can simply strip all HTML with adjacent newlines using this function:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\n*</?\w[^>]*>\n*", "")
```

Result:

```
Text to get
```

Explanation:

- `\n*` - optional newlines
- `<` - literal `<`
- `/?` - optional slash (end of tag)
- `\w` - word char (HTML tags start with `a`...`z`)
- `[^>]*` - scan over everything until just before `>`
- `>` - literal `>`
- `\n*` - optional newlines

Note that his regex is not foolproof. It will fail if you have a `>` in an attribute value, such as `<h1 title="path > to > foo">`. For a solid solution you'd need to use an HTML parser.

Comment: @user2240778: Any questions? Does this fit your needs?

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; ">(.+)</")
```